# 3 models query data in cgridview using yii framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

how can we accomplish the below query result in cgridview using 3 models.?

```
select a.id,
   a.name,
   b.group_id,
   c.id,
   c.client_id,
   c.title
from           users_phone_numbers a,
 phone_number_group_assignment b,
                 client_groups c
where    a.id = b.phone_number_id
and      b.group_id=c.id;
```

plz reply thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider)

```
$rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('... query ...')->queryAll();
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'a.id',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
              'a.name, b.group_id, ...',
        ),
     ),
));
```

Pass `$dataProvider` as the DataProvider to your grid view.

Comment: by this way Query is done ok. but how can we sort/filter records of multitple models at a single page using cgridview using yii framework cgridview???

Comment: Edited my answer as described in the link provided. But not sure if sorting will work.